# Using Get method to pull pages to the index page

Tags: php, get, navigation

I am trying to learn to use the `$get`method to pull in my pages from my nav bar. 
This is how I am set up,

I have a root dir with a index page. 
I have a directory called pages

upon landing at the index page I want it to pull in 
pages/home.php
 then of course upon navigating pull in the other pages

home.php
contact.php 
services.php 
employees.php 
dashboard.php

I have tried many different ways to get this to work.

This is whats in my index page

```
<?php
$page = index.php

$page = $_GET['page']; 
if(!file_exists("pages/".$page.".php")){ 
$page="404" 
} 
include("pages/".$page.".php"); 
?>
```

this is my nav.php file

```
<ul>
<?php
$pages = array(
    "pages/home.php" => "Home", 
    "pages/contact.php" => "Contact Us", 
    "pages/services.php" => "services", 
    "pages/employees.php" => "Employees", 
    "pages/dashboard.php" => "Dashboard");

foreach ($pages as $url => $label) {
  echo '<li ';

  if(basename($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])== basename($url)){   // this line
        echo "class='active'";                              // this line
   }                                                        // and this line
  echo '><a href=', "$url", '>', "$label", '</a></li>';
}
?>
</ul>
```

and at the top of every page I have this

```
<?php
$page = 'PageName.php';
?>
```

If someone could help me make this work I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$_GET does not work that way. $_GET gets data by the url AFTER the question mark, for example:

```
http://example.com/index.php?p=home
```

The index.php page controls the GET request, traditionally. Doing the above sets a GET request for variable 'p' and assigns 'p' a value of 'home'. A common way I deal with GET requests is with the below code, tweaked to fit your code.

```
$p = (isset($_GET['p'])) ? $_GET['p'] : "";

if (file_exists("$p.php")) {
  include("$p.php");
}
```

Comment: So this is the only thing that needs to go on the index page?

Comment: You also have to set your links as `index.php?p=contact`, `index.php?p=services`, etc.

Comment: I appreciate you. I am having a horrible time understanding this been at it for a while. If you dont have the time to write it out could you maybe point me in the direction of and article that could explain this to me?

Comment: Not sure if I can link but you can find an example here: http://pastebin.com/KrhpHJd4

Comment: thank you for that. I guess I am just not getting where all this data goes, how it all comes together... SO all that goes in one file? the index.php file? then what do I need to add the the nav.php file and the pages to make this all come together and work?

Comment: I'm assuming by your code that you want to include() pages into the current page (index.php) so you can change only the main content, not the header and footer of the page. Yes, all the code there should all be on the index.php. index.php controls the entire website so all your pages will start with index.php, the only thing that changes is the 'p' GET request.

Comment: ok thanks to you I the links works and change the url but the pages dont populate. the pages are in the pages directory. I am trying to figure out where to add that.

Comment: Simply put "pages/" on the `file_exists` and `include` code. I forgot to add the pages directory. See link: http://pastebin.com/ChLyy4T1